# Hide elements in browser without editing HTML?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My employer is switching to a new Web software system, which we will use to track student information. The software is customizable to an extent, but many fields that the system offers cannot be disabled. For example, I would not want or need to track Social Security Numbers, so I would like to hide that field permanently on the page where it appears.

These fields are hard-coded as table rows, and I know I could hide those with `style="display:none"` in CSS. However, I do not have access to the system's style sheet.

Is it possible to set up a filter in my own browser where I could style the pages in this new software system? If so, would it be limited to my own PC, or could I export and share the file with coworkers to use? Note: the software is limited to IE (11).

Comment: If you can't change the HTML and you don't have access to the CSS, how do you expect to be able to change anything? Do you have access to the site's JavaScript files?

Comment: You can create a bookmarklet that hides the rows when clicked

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/320707/customize-internet-explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the row, you can do it with a user style sheet.

> IE allows you to use your own StyleSheet directly from its accessibility settings.
>   Click the IE9 tools menu icon in the top right, (or use the Keyboard shortcut: ALT+X).
>   Then open Internet Options, click on the Accessibility button, and chose Format documents using my style sheet.
>   Then you need to chose a CSS file, using the Browse function.

[Source](http://brugbart.com/custom-style-sheets)
[image] 
And your CSS would look something like:

```
table tr.socialsecurity{
display:none;
}
```

Use the browsers inspector and find the rows `class`. If id doesn't have one, you can use `nth-of-type()`.
Note: you need to restart your browser for the CSS to take effect. To use this on multiple computers, send the Style-sheet to your coworkers and have them install it.
 **As the OP asked for an IE answer, I only contained the relevant instructions. Note that this can be done in ALL Browsers. [Instructions can be found here](http://brugbart.com/custom-style-sheets)**

Comment: Most web browsers have this feature (not just IE), specifying a CSS style sheet to be automatically applied against any loaded web page.

Comment: @BasilBourque I know :D the OP said they only have access to IE, so i only posted the IE relevant answer.

Comment: This is great! I will test your method and see how it goes. Thanks so much!

Comment: To expect every visitor to the site to do that, though, is a bit much. And, even if they do, what happens when they visit another site that has a table with rows that have the class "socialsecurity"?

Comment: @Shaggy what i perceived the OP was asking was that it is a secure site, with limited users. What they are probably doing is not displaying it as they don't need the information, and they obviously do not want anyone else who happens to be near to see it.

Comment: As your answer was accepted, it appears your perception was correct thus rendering my points moot.

Comment: @Shaggy thanks for pointing it out anyway :) maybe it will help someone sometime.

Comment: Actually, it might be an idea to add a disclaimer to you answer for the benefit of anyone stumbling across it in the future who's looking to make changes to a *public* site but doesn't have access to its HTML or CSS.

Comment: @Shaggy Good Idea, i'll add one.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access both HTML or CSS you cannot hide your rows

Answer (score 0):

Might work adding your own style sheets through Accessibility Options

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking about setting up your own custom style sheet, IE allows you to create a user style sheet for all pages you visit.

**"Installing" the stylesheet**

1. Open the Tools > Internet Options dialog.
2. On the General tab, select Accessibility.
3. On the User style sheet section, select the box marked Format documents using my style sheet.
4. Press Browse and locate your stylesheet.
5. Select your file then press Open to install it.

Note: You may need to restart your browser for the style sheet to take effect.

Rinse and repeat for any other computer.